# Best practice for language localisation and regional language auto-detect in HTML

Tags: html, localization

What's current best practice for language localisation and auto-detection in HTML? I've tried to find a definitive guide that seems up to date, but all I find seems rather old, so I'm guessing there's a HTML5 style standardised approach?

For content ideally I'd like to avoid databases, but I'm happy to link to a JSON or CSV file.

I'd like the URLs to be elegant i.e. site.com/es/ or site.com/de/